# How to match a Column from a calculation column (non-existing) within the same table

Tags: sql, case

Well, I have to match the values from the column 'TotalAmount' with the calculation of two columns (UnitPrice and Quantity)

My guess is that I need to use Case statement but I don't know where to locate the multiplication.

Also, maybe I should create another column within the same table with the results of the multiplication and then do the matching?

Here is the table:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EcG0m.jpg)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WITH T AS ( SELECT (quantity*unitprice) as total 
              FROM tb1 ) 
(SELECT * 
   FROM T 
  INNER JOIN tb1 ON tb1.totalAmount=T.total
)
```

Below are the screenshots
[Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QshzU.png)

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/giq98.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please [do not upload images of code/data/errors](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). If you want to share example of output it's better to share it by text.

Answer (score 0):

If you need just to filter rows, so that `totalAmount = quantity * unitPrice`, you can use simple where statement like this.

```sql
SELECT *
  FROM table1 t1
 WHERE t1.totalAmount = t1.quantity * t1.unitPrice
```

If you need self join rows with that condition you also can do it:

```sql
SELECT *
  FROM table1 t1
  JOIN table1 t2 
    ON t1.totalAmount = t2.quantity * t2.unitPrice
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is what you need.

```sql
-- First you should select the id, UnitPrice, Quantity and TotalAmount

SELECT id, UnitPrice, Quantity, TotalAmount,

-- In this section is the condition for the checking of TotalAmount to 
-- UnitPrice and Quantity.

CASE

    WHEN TotalAmount = (UnitPrice * Quantity) THEN 'total amount is equal 

to UnitPrice * Quantity'

    ELSE 'not match'

-- In this column is the result.

END AS 'Status'

FROM your_table_name;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I only need to print out the values that don't match. So, I check with the calculation and if the values from it dont match the values on ToTalAmount, I should get only the ones which arent match.